# Apache Camel FTP File should be consumed by single server

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I Am having two servers which poll to same ftp location. when a file is placed in that location both the servers are picking the files. But I need only one server to pick the file and process and delete.I am using Camel 2.16.2 Version. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Camel FTP uses most of camel-File2 API internally. All, camel file the options are inherited.

There are many strategies to avoid parallel processing of same file.
Use preMove, moveFailed, readLock, readLockRemoveOnCommit Camel-File options.

For instance you could use below parameters.

```
ftp://{{input.folder}}?readLock=rename&preMove=.inprogress&moveFailed=.error
```